# BeautifulSoup is not returning all elements using CSS selectors

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I am using `.select()` with BeautifulSoup and I am not sure why only part of my expect results are being returned.

My HTML has a format of

```
<div class="a">
  <a class="class-type">
  <a class="class-type">
  <a class="class-type">
  <a class="class-type">
  .... {12 times}
</div>
<div class="a">
  <a class="class-type">
  <a class="class-type">
  <a class="class-type">
  <a class="class-type">
  .... {12 times}
</div>
<div class="a">
  <a class="class-type">
  <a class="class-type">
  <a class="class-type">
  <a class="class-type">
  .... {12 times}
</div>
```

Code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
item_urls = soup.select(".css-ix8km1")
```

returns only `12` items when I am expecting 36 items returned

Comment: Can you post your link and code you are using. Or the original response text instead of <a class="class-type">.

Comment: @BittoBennichan HTML is too big but the URL: `https://www.sephora.com/shop/face-makeup?pageSize=300`  and the `div` with the attribute `data-comp=ProductGrid`. I am trying to grab all the `hrefs` within that tag

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned by cody, you will need to use some mechanism like selenium.I tried out the page down and was able to get the output with the following code. You need to close the popup ad by clicking on the the 'X' button before you apply page down.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import selenium
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/home/bitto/chromedriver') #change this
driver.get("https://www.sephora.com/shop/face-makeup?pageSize=300")
#to close the popup ad
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='css-1mfnet7 ']"))
    )
    element.click()
except selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException:
    print("Ad was not found")
time.sleep(1) #not preferred but will do for now
elem = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body")
item_urls=[]
no_of_pagedowns = 3

while no_of_pagedowns:
    elem.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
    time.sleep(5) #not preferred but will do for now
    no_of_pagedowns-=1
post_elems =driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='css-ix8km1']")
for elem in post_elems:
    item_urls.append(elem.get_attribute("href"))
print(item_urls)
```

Ouput

```
['https://www.sephora.com/product/pro-filtr-soft-matte-longwear-foundation-P87985432?icid2=products%20grid:p87985432:product', 'https://www.sephora.com/product/pro-filt-r-instant-retouch-concealer-P88779809?icid2=products%20grid:p88779809:product', 'https://www.sephora.com/product/radiant-creamy-concealer-P377873?icid2=products%20grid:p377873:product', 'https://www.sephora.com/product/translucent-loose-setting-powder-P109908?icid2=products%20grid:p109908:product', 'https://www.sephora.com/product/pro-filt-r-instant-retouch-setting-powder-P88779810?icid2=products%20grid:p88779810:product', 'https://www.sephora.com/product/diamond-bomb-all-over-diamond-veil-P85225585?icid2=products%20grid:p85225585:product', 'https://www.sephora.com/product/the-silk-canvas-P428661?icid2=products%20grid:p428661:product', 'https://www.sephora.com/product/pineapple-my-eye-collector-s-set-P435947?icid2=products%20grid:p435947:product', 'https://www.sephora.com/product/double-wear-stay-in-place-makeup-P378284?icid2=products%20grid:p378284:product', 'https://www.sephora.com/product/ultra-hd-invisible-cover-foundation-P398321?icid2=products%20grid:p398321:product', 'https://www.sephora.com/product/all-nighter-long-lasting-makeup-setting-spray-P263504?icid2=products%20grid:p263504:product', 'https://www.sephora.com/product/your-skin-but-better-cc-cream-spf-50-P411885?icid2=products%20grid:p411885:product', 'https://www.sephora.com/product/luminous-silk-foundation-P393401?icid2=products%20grid:p393401:product', 'https://www.sephora.com/product/born-this-way-P397517?icid2=products%20grid:p397517:product', 'https://www.sephora.com/product/born-this-way-super-coverage-multi-use-sculpting-concealer-P432298?icid2=products%20grid:p432298:product', 'https://www.sephora.com/product/lock-it-tattoo-foundation-P311138?icid2=products%20grid:p311138:product', 'https://www.sephora.com/product/fresh-face-kit-P440030?icid2=products%20grid:p440030:product', 'https://www.sephora.com/product/teint-idole-ultra-24h-long-wear-foundation-P308201?icid2=products%20grid:p308201:product', 'https://www.sephora.com/product/fauxfilter-foundation-P424302?icid2=products%20grid:p424302:product', 'https://www.sephora.com/product/creaseless-concealer-P433206?icid2=products%20grid:p433206:product', 'https://www.sephora.com/product/bareminerals-original-foundation-broad-spectrum-spf-15-P61003?icid2=products%20grid:p61003:product', 'https://www.sephora.com/product/shimmering-skin-perfector-pressed-P381176?icid2=products%20grid:p381176:product', 'https://www.sephora.com/product/tinted-moisturizer-broad-spectrum-P109936?icid2=products%20grid:p109936:product', 'https://www.sephora.com/product/veil-mineral-primer-P210575?icid2=products%20grid:p210575:product']
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is only the first 12 items are rendered in the response, the rest are lazily loaded via the site's javascript code. This can be confirmed by requesting that url with `curl` and counting the number of instances of the class string:

```
$ curl -s 'https://www.sephora.com/shop/face-makeup?pageSize=300' | grep -o css-ix8km1 | wc -l
13
```

You may need to utilize a mechanism that will execute javascript, like Selenium WebDriver.

Comment: I am using Selenium WebDriver so Javascript is rendered but with `.select()` I am still only able to grab 12.

Comment: @Liondancer I see. Well, if you manually use the site, you will see that the mechanism that loads each additional batch is the act of scrolling down. So you would have to reproduce the scrolling with WebDriver. There are many SO answers on this topic.

Comment: ahhh that makes sense. Thank you! i will try that